# "Rip-off central" or?

Tags: word-request, idioms, expressions

I wonder what I should call a (market / bazar / shopping center, etc) where things are sold much more expensive than they worth and usually salespeople rip off whoever wants to purchase something there?

I have heard the term "rip-off central", but I cannot find any reliable confirming source for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Rip-off central* is a kind of slang term, and not one that would be commonly used. If anything, using just *rip off* would be better, even though that's still somewhat colloquial.

A more common term for such a place is [**tourist trap**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tourist%20trap):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : a place that attracts and exploits tourists
>   // The street market is a *tourist trap* that mostly sells cheap souvenirs.
>   // That hotel is just a *tourist trap*.

Such areas are known by natives to sell items or offer services that are overpriced or low in quality, or both.

It's only tourists and other newcomers to the area who will do business there, because they are unaware of its reputation.

Comment: central is often used in slang, preceded by many sorts of adjectives.

Comment: Thank you Jason. Just to avoid my friend purchase something in such a place I should tell him e.g. "try not to buy anything from there. **There is a tourist trap.**" Right?

Comment: I would say ***it's*** *a tourist trap*, but yes.